# Turquoise Blue Font in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to know what the light blue/turquoise blue font in Matlab means. I am currently working on Bayesian Optimisation in Matlab and whilst going to some previous students' code, I came across a weird blue font colour I have never seen before in their function definition. I have checked my colour scheme settings in Matlab and this turquoise blue does not appear in the list of set colours. See the attached picture for reference.

[image: Turquoise Blue Font colour in Matlab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default this color means that the corresponding variable has [shared scope](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-variable-scope-in-editor.html). This can be because it is

- a [global](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38470) variable (its scope is shared with the command window);
- a [persistent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-38521) variable (its scope is shared across subsequent calls to this function); or
- a variable that is used in a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html#f0-50984) (its scope is shared between the nested and parent functions).

Thus, this color indicates in general that the value of that variable can be affected from outside the function.

The color can be changed in the Matlab preferences window. The window also shows some example code that illustrates this:

[image]

Comment: How enlightening, thanks!

Comment: @JDS Glad I could help!